# PHP Scrape - Create multidimensional arrays from results - current code only returning one result

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, scrape

I'm quite new to PHP and am creating a web scraper for a project.  From this website, https://www.bloglovin.com/en/blogs/1/2/all, I am scraping the blog title, blog url, image url and concatenating a follow through link for later use.  As you can see on the page, there are several fields with information for each blogger.

Here is my PHP code so far;

```
<?php

        // Function to make GET request using cURL
        function curlGet($url) {
            $ch = curl_init(); // Initialising cURL session
            // Setting cURL options
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            $results = curl_exec($ch); // Executing cURL session
            curl_close($ch); // Closing cURL session
            return $results; // Return the results
        }

        $blogStats = array();

        function returnXPathObject($item) {
            $xmlPageDom = new DomDocument(); 
            @$xmlPageDom->loadHTML($item); 
            $xmlPageXPath = new DOMXPath($xmlPageDom); 
            return $xmlPageXPath; 
        }

        $blPage = curlGet('https://www.bloglovin.com/en/blogs/1/2/all');
        $blPageXpath = returnXPathObject($blPage); 

        $title = $blPageXpath->query('//*[@id="content"]//div/a/h2/span[1]');
                if ($title->length > 0) {
            $blogStats['title'] = $title->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }

        $url = $blPageXpath->query('//*[@id="content"]//div/a/h2/span[2]');
            if ($url->length > 0) {
            $blogStats['url'] = $url->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }

        $img = $blPageXpath->query('//*[@id="content"]//div/a/div/@href');
            if ($img->length > 0) {
            $blogStats['img'] = $img->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }

        $followLink = $blPageXpath->query('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div/a/@href');
            if ($followLink->length > 0) {
                $blogStats['followLink'] = 'http://www.bloglovin.com' . $followLink->item($i)->nodeValue;
        }


        print_r($blogStats);


        /*$data = $blogStats;
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);*/
    ?>
```

Currently, this only returns:

```
Array ( [title] => Fashion Toast [url] => fashiontoast.com [followLink] => http://www.bloglovin.com/blog/4735/fashion-toast )
```

My question is, what is the best way to loop through each of the results? I've been looking through Stack Overflow and am struggling to find an answer to my question, and my heads going a bit loopy!  If anyone could advise me or put me in the right direction, that would be fantastic.

Thank you.

Update:
I'm very sure this is wrong, i'm receiving errors!

```
<?php

    // Function to make GET request using cURL
    function curlGet($url) {
        $ch = curl_init(); // Initialising cURL session
        // Setting cURL options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $results = curl_exec($ch); // Executing cURL session
        curl_close($ch); // Closing cURL session
        return $results; // Return the results
    }

    $blogStats = array();

    function returnXPathObject($item) {
        $xmlPageDom = new DomDocument(); 
        @$xmlPageDom->loadHTML($item); 
        $xmlPageXPath = new DOMXPath($xmlPageDom); 
        return $xmlPageXPath; 
    }

$blogPage = curlGet('https://www.bloglovin.com/en/blogs/1/2/all');
    $blogPageXpath = returnXPathObject($blogPage);

    $blogger = $blogPageXpath->query('//*[@id="content"]/div/@data-blog-id');
    if ($blogger->length > 0) {
    $blogStats[] = $blogger->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }


    foreach($blogger as $id) {

            $blPage = curlGet('https://www.bloglovin.com/en/blogs/1/2/all');
            $blPageXpath = returnXPathObject($blPage);

            $title = $blPageXpath->query('//*[@id="content"]//div/a/h2/span[1]');
                if ($title->length > 0) {
                $blogStats[$id]['title'] = $title->item(0)->nodeValue;
            }

            $url = $blPageXpath->query('//*[@id="content"]//div/a/h2/span[2]');
                if ($url->length > 0) {
                $blogStats[$id]['url'] = $url->item(0)->nodeValue;
            }

            $img = $blPageXpath->query('//*[@id="content"]//div/a/div/@href');
                if ($img->length > 0) {
                $blogStats[$id]['img'] = $img->item(0)->nodeValue;
            }

            $followLink = $blPageXpath->query('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div/a/@href');
                if ($followLink->length > 0) {
                $blogStats[$id]['followLink'] = 'http://www.bloglovin.com' . $followLink->item($i)->nodeValue;
            }
            }



    print_r($blogStats);


    /*$data = $blogStats;
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);*/ ?>
```

Comment: oh.. of course that will be wrong. $blogger does not exist. As I said, you have to modify the way $blPage is defined so that it's actually different in each iteration. I wrote foreach in case you have an array of bloggers with their id, but I can't do that part for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you want to actually add a dimension to your array. I guess bloggers have a unique id, or somesuch identifier.

moreover, your code seems to execute only once? it might need to be in something like a foreach

I can't do that part for you, but you need an array containing each blogger, or a way to do a while, or for! you have to understand how to iterate over your different bloggers by yourself :)

here an exemple of array of bloggers

```
[14]['bloggerOne']
[15]['bloggerTwo']
[16]['bloggerThree']
```

```
foreach ($blogger as $id => $name)  
 {

$blPage = curlGet('https://www.bloglovin.com/en/blogs/1/2/' . $name); 
// here you have something to do so that $blPage is actually different with each iteration, like changing the url
$blPageXpath = returnXPathObject($blPage); 

$title = $blPageXpath->query('//*[@id="content"]//div/a/h2/span[1]');
            if ($title->length > 0) {
        $blogStats[$id]['title'] = $title->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }

    $url = $blPageXpath->query('//*[@id="content"]//div/a/h2/span[2]');
        if ($url->length > 0) {
        $blogStats[$id]['url'] = $url->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }

    $img = $blPageXpath->query('//*[@id="content"]//div/a/div/@href');
        if ($img->length > 0) {
        $blogStats[$id]['img'] = $img->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }

    $followLink = $blPageXpath->query('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div/a/@href');
        if ($followLink->length > 0) {
            $blogStats[$id]['followLink'] = 'http://www.bloglovin.com' . $followLink->item($i)->nodeValue;
    }


  }
```

so after the foreach, you array could look like:

```
['12345']['title'] = whatever
         ['url'] = url
         ['img'] = foo
         ['followLink'] = bar
['4141']['title'] = other
        ['url'] = urlss
        ['img'] = foo
        ['followLink'] = bar
['7415']['title'] = still
        ['url'] = url4
        ['img'] = foo
        ['followLink'] = bar
```

Comment: Each blogger has a unique 'data-blog-id', so could utilise this. Sorry to sound silly, but do you mean that i'd xpath to the blogger id in the 'foreach', or put the whole codeblock in the foreach? Still a bit of noob!

Comment: oh sorry for not putting it myself, yeah, the whole codeblock in the foreach so that it gets done multiple times with a different blogger each time. I'll edit it now.

Comment: sorry, I'm still struggling a little, see update! Maybe diving into a project wasn't such a fantastic idea.  But I appreciate your help so far, thank you.

Comment: alright. I edited it again, but you can't just copy that code and expect it to work :) you have to adapt it to your own code, I have no way of writing it exactly the way it will fit in your script!

Comment: thank you for all of your help so far, I really appreciate it. I'm going to come back to it tomorrow (my brain's a little frazzled) and implement your advice then.  I have created a $bloggers loop to access the id, its just a case of making it work with foreach!